# Unable to run ggsci

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-golden-gate

I am a newbie  to Goldengate. 
I have installed Oracle GoldenGate 12c for Oracle Database 11.2.0.4.
The installation was successful but after installation I was unable to open ggsci 
i tried opening it with command prompt but not able to open it.

the ggsci window and within a second it closes without displaying any error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that some of windows files were missing ..adding them to the same folder where ggsci resides starts the process